# очередь задач на WinRT

Tags: c++, winrt

Здравствуйте!
Поставил себе задачу, а грамотно объяснить гуглу что хочу - не могу.

Нужно под WinRT реализовать очередь задач - объект, выполняющий задачи одну за другой.
Есть несколько паралельно выполняющихся потоков. Потоки выполняют однотипные задачи - читают или записывают данные в файл. Потоки должны добавлять в очередь свои задачи и ожидать их выполнения.

Пока что представляю себе это так: поток добавляет в очередь что-то вроде IAsyncOperation, и ждет ее выполнения. Очередь выполняет добавленные задачи, выполненные задачи удаляются из очереди.

Кто-нибудь знает, есть ли уже реализация подобных вещей? Или в какую сторону смотреть если придется писать это самому?

Answer (score 1):

Судя по всему, вам нужен producer-consumer.

Это делается так:

```
readonly BlockingCollection<YourTask> q = new BlockingCollection<YourTask>();

// добавление 
while (есть ещё задания)
{
    YourTask t = new YourTask(...);
    q.Add(s);
}

q.CompleteAdding();
```

Исполнитель выглядит так:

```
var consumerThreads = new List<Thread>();
for (int i = 0; i < consumerCount; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() => Consumer(q));
    t.Start();
    consumerThreads.Add(t);
}

void Consumer(BlockingCollection<YourTask> q)
{
    foreach (var t in q.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        // выполнить задание t
    }
}
```

Comment: жаль что не под с++, но для начала что то. А нет ли случаем объекта, который вмещал бы в себе лямбду, стартовал выполнение не с момента создания (как то, что создается create_task create_async) и отчитывался о выполнении? Тогда такой объект можно стартовать, выполнить, удалить из очереди. Ну, и как я понимаю, стартовать выполнение очереди придется при каждом добавлении т.к. ожидается, что очередь в основном будет простаивать и ожидать операций

Comment: @РомаАрхипкин: На C++/CLI (или как оно там) переводится очевидный образом.

Comment: @РомаАрхипкин: Есть такой, это `Task<T>`. Но если вы уж пишете асинхронную логику, убегайте с C++ и пишите сразу на C#, там есть великий и могучий `async`/`await`. А зачем вам знать, что задание отработало?

Comment: @РомаАрхипкин: Рестарт вроде не нужен. Ну да, очередь будет часто простаивать, ну так пусть себе простаивает, вам жалко? :) Запускаете всю механику один раз в начале, и всё.

Comment: @РомаАрхипкин: Consumer не остановится, пока вы не скажете `q.CompleteAdding();` (если вы об этом)

Comment: ну не совсем очевидным, в винрт многое с ног на голову перевернуто от того что есть в си/кли. Тот же самый таск не имеет метода старт, только "получить" и "ждать пока выполнится", то есть стартует в момент создания. На шарп бежать не хочу, т.к. часть программы должны быть железно на си++, а я только год как разбираюсь в нем. Держать два языка в голове пока сложновато

Comment: @РомаАрхипкин: Мне кажется, C++/CLI существенно сложнее, чем шарп. И чем C++, тоже. Воля, конечно, ваша.

Comment: Начинать то я пробовал с шарпа, и да, был эффект "вау, это же просто!". Потом решил перейти на си, т.к. по отзывам для тяжелых задач подходит лучше. Пока, что сегодняшнего вечера вполне справлялся с си, но сейчас поставил себе дейсвтительно сложную задачу - организовать параллельный доступ к файлу с минимальной памятью.

Comment: С **реально** минимальной памятью? Тогда вам придётся отказаться от рантайм-поддержки файлов и вести работу через нативное API, наверное?

Comment: ну, реально достигаемой. Как мне сказали в англоязычном мсдне, вне директории программы разрешен только рантайм - доступ. Я бы и рад использовать стд-шный доступ, но приходится городить такие вот вещи. Описанная мной модель доступа занимает памяти ровно столько, сколько нужно. Если сделать доступ через разные стримы (без этой асинхронности), то происходят скачки занимаемой памяти на 10 мбайт. На телефоне может привести к вылету. Но если вы знаете, как обойти систему - с удовольствием послушаю

Comment: @РомаАрхипкин: Не, я с телефоном не очень дружу. :-( Сорри.

Comment: @VladD _`for (int i = 0; i < consumerCount; i++) { Thread(() => Consumer(q)); ...`_ -- если q - это какая-то переменная, то возможна проблема: [Почему делегат из отдельного потока добавляет неправильные данные](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480645/)

Comment: @Stack: Вы правы. Чтобы подчеркнуть неизменность объекта коллекции, добавил к объявлению `readonly`.

Comment: @VladD разные потоки, один q -- получается producer-consumer'Ы. и каждый из потоков ждет данные из q.GetConsumingEnumerable(). не будет такого, что один поток захватит несколько элементов, а другие будут простаивать? но они все точно будут простаивать между обработкой последнего элемента в одном из потоков и вызовом CompleteAdding.

Comment: @Stack: Угу, это специально пример с несколькими consumer'ами. В принципе, ничего не гарантирует честного распределения, теоретически не исключена возможность, что вся работа достанется только одному из consumer'ов. Это не влияет на правильность кода по идее. В принципе да, все consumer'ы будут простаивать в ожидании задания, если CompleteAdding будет вызвано с большой задержкой.

Answer (score 0):

Элементарно, IMHO. Поток вызывает CreateEvent, добавляет новый ивент в очередь задач вместе с данными задачи, потом WaitForSingleObject. Тот кто разбирает очередь задач вызывает SetEvent и удаляет задачу из очереди. Поток продолжает выполнение, освобождает хэндл через CloseHandle и все сначала. Добавить синхронизацию работы с очередью только надо.

Comment: Это какое-то новое, незнакомое мне значение слова «элементарно».

Comment: @Владимир: стаж мой всего год, поэтому можно чуть подробнее про эти вызовы? В винРТ конкретно разрешены эти: CreateEventExA и WaitForSingleObjectEx. Это что то из WRL?

Comment: Это WinAPI. https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx - про одну из функций, остальные описаны там же.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов А не могли бы Вы хоть чуть чуть показать как это делается?

Comment: Что именно вас интересует? Создание потоков? Создание событий? Вообще в MSDN обычно есть примеры использования API.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов А чем Ваше решение отличается от создания concurrency::task_group? Хоть что то нашел на МСДН. В общем, эта группа имеет функцию run_and_wait(lambda). Проверил на двух задачах - первая долгая вторая короткая, выполняются последовательно

Comment: Мое решение использует WinAPI напрямую

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, есть решение "из коробки"

```
concurrency::task_group tg;
tg.run_and_wait([]()
{
    //содержимое задачи 1
});

tg.run_and_wait([]()
{
    //содержимое задачи 2
});
```

Также, обнаружил что std::task_handle не выполняется при создании