# Почему делегат из отдельного потока добавляет неправильные данные в UI-поток?

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность

В отдельных потоках происходит вычисление, результат которых надо вывести в  форму. Для передачи данных в UI-поток [надо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418461/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0) вызывать Control.BeginInvoke

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

void addText(Form f, int res) { 
  f.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Text = res.ToString(), Dock = DockStyle.Top });
}

var f = new Form();
f.Load += (s, e) => {
  Task.Run(() => {
     for(var result=0; result < 5; result++)
        f.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => addText(f, result) ));
  });      
};

f.ShowDialog();
```

Но в форме выводятся неправильные значения. Во всех TextBox'ах выводится 5.

---

Вызываю BeginInvoke из UI-потока

```
f.Load += (s, e) => {
  var result = "a";
  f.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => addText(f, result) ));
  result = "b";
  f.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => addText(f, result) ));
```

};

Но в форме также выводятся неправильные значения. В TextBox'ах выводится "b".
Почему так и как вывести правильный результат в форму?
Возможно ли избавиться от вызовов BeginInvoke в разных частях кода?

Answer (score 4):

Вызов BeginInvoke ставит делегат в специальную очередь, которая обрабатывается в UI-потоке. К моменту вызова делегата, в result оказывается новое значение, а не то, которое было в момент вызова BeginInvoke.
Если в addText надо передать result, существующий на момент вызова BeginInvoke, то строку

```
f.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => addText(f, result) ));
```

надо заменить на следующую

```
f.BeginInvoke(
   new Action<string>(v => addText(f, v)), 
   result.ToString()    // передается в v в момент вызова делегата
   );
```

Т.к. f это ссылка на Form, и мы знаем, что она не изменится, то передавать ее в BeginInvoke не надо.
При работе с замыканиями надо соблюдать правило: **переменные, которые могут измениться к моменту вызова делегата, должны быть переданы в метод BeginInvoke при его вызове**.

---

Вместо того, чтобы вызывать BeginInvoke в разных частях кода можно перенести BeginInvoke в метод addText и вызывать его после проверки InvokeRequired.

```
void addText(Form frm, int res) {
  if (frm.InvokeRequired)    // true - если вызван не из UI-потока
     frm.BeginInvoke(
        new Action<Form, int>((f, r) => addText(f, r)),
        frm, res);   // передается в (f, r)
  else
     frm.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Text = res.ToString(), Dock = DockStyle.Top });
}

var f = new Form();

f.Load += (s, e) => {
   Task.Run(() => {
      for (var result = 0; result< 5; result++)
         addText(f, result);
    });
};

f.ShowDialog();
```

Хотя в методе addText определен вызов addText, но это **не рекурсия**, т.к. BeginInvoke добавляет делегат вместе с данными в специальную очередь, которая обрабатывается в UI-потоке.

Comment: Переменная f точно так же может поменяться, нет?

Comment: @PashaPash _"Переменная f точно так же может поменяться, нет?"_ -- это строка из примера в вопросе, где f : Form - не меняется. но вообще - да, все переменные, которые могут измениться к моменту вызова делегата, должны быть переданы в метод BeginInvoke при его вызове

Comment: учитывая сам синтаксис замыканий - за этим достаточно тяжело уследить :(

Answer (score 4):

Альтернативное решение той же проблемы - не использовать одну и ту же переменную для хранения результатов двух разных операций:

```
f.Load += (s, e) => {
  var resultA = "a";
  f.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => addText(f, resultA) ));
  var resultB = "b";
  f.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => addText(f, resultB) ));
};
```

Comment: В новом C# будут read-only-переменные (`let resultA = "a"` вместо `var`), с ними проблема уйдёт.

Comment: Почему не `Invoke` просто?

Answer (score 3):

§Цикл for

Наверное, это самый классический пример, который приводят все:

```
public void Run()
{
  var actions = new List<Action>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    actions.Add(() => Console.WriteLine(i));
  foreach (var action in actions)
    action();
}
```

В этом примере сделана типичная ошибка. Начинающие программисты думаю, что этот код выведет "0 1 2", но на самом деле он выведет "3 3 3". Такое странное поведение легко понять, если взглянуть на развёрнутую версию этого метода:

```
public void Run()
{
  var actions = new List<Action>();
  DisplayClass c = new DisplayClass();
  for (c.i = 0; c.i < 3; c.i++)
    list.Add(c.Action);
  foreach (Action action in list)
    action();
}

private sealed class DisplayClass
{
  public int i;

  public void Action()
  {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
  }
}
```

В таком случае часто говорят, что переменная замыкается по ссылке, а не по значению. Эту особенность замыканий многие осуждают, как непонятную, хотя она является достаточно логичной для тех, кто хорошо представляет, что скрыто под капотом замыканий. Эту тему очень подробно обсуждает Эрик Липперт в постах О вреде замыканий на переменных цикла и Замыкания на переменных цикла. Часть 2.

[§Неочевидности в использовании C#-замыканий](http://aakinshin.net/ru/blog/dotnet/closures/)

[Замыкания на переменных цикла в C# 5](https://habrahabr.ru/post/141270/)