# Установка анонимного метода обработчиком события в цикле foreach

Tags: c#, c#-faq

Определяю класс-издатель события

```
class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Car(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public event EventHandler Started;
    public void Start()
    {
        if (Started != null)
            Started(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

, класс-подписчик

```
class Driver
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Driver(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

, тестирую

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var fomenko = new Driver("Фоменко");
    var shumaher = new Driver("Шумахер");
    var vasya = new Driver("Вася");
    Driver[] drivers = new Driver[]
        {
            fomenko, shumaher, vasya
        };
    List<Car> cars = new List<Car>();
    foreach (var driver in drivers)
    {
        var car = new Car
            (
                driver == fomenko ?
                "Маруся"
                : driver == shumaher ?
                "Ф1"
                : "Запорожец"
            );                
        car.Started += delegate(object o, EventArgs ea)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Стартовала машина {0} с пилотом {1}",
                    car.Name, driver.Name);
            };
        cars.Add(car);
    }

    foreach (var car in cars)
    {
        car.Start();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Выдаёт

```
Стартовала машина Маруся с пилотом Вася
Стартовала машина Ф1 с пилотом Вася
Стартовала машина Запорожец с пилотом Вася
```

А хотелось бы

```
Стартовала машина Маруся с пилотом Фоменко
Стартовала машина Ф1 с пилотом Шумахер
Стартовала машина Запорожец с пилотом Вася
```

Почему так происходит? Как исправить?

---

Версия C# 3.0 .Net 3.5

Comment: А посадить водителя в машину не пробовали? Резко проще становится логика и проблем будет меньше. Это я так, мимо крокодил. Тут что-то с замыканиями, но я в них не понимаю =)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Почему делегат из отдельного потока добавляет неправильные данные в UI-поток?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480645/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b2-ui-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba)

Comment: Где-то был более каноничный вопрос, но я не смог его найти.

Comment: @Monk, я когда-нибудь научусь делать хороший пример проблемы)) в этот раз не получилось. Нужно решение именно проблемы подписки на события в цикле, с использованием переменных видимых в блоке цикла.

Comment: @andreycha, проблема по ссылке вероятно схожа, а может даже одна по своей сути. Но из-за многопоточности  сильно усложнена для понимания решения в моём случае.

Comment: Прочитайте самый нижний ответ.

Comment: Если внутри форича скопипастить водителя в переменную - оно поможет или нет? Я чет туплю.

Comment: Кстати, `public EventHandler Started;` неправильно, нужно `public event EventHandler Started;`

Comment: @4per: А какая у вас версия .NET?

Comment: @andreycha: Хм. Начиная с C# 5, переменная `foreach` каждый раз новая. Гляньте, например, абзац с Update [тут](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/).

Comment: @andreycha, прочитал, конечно. Не могу признать, что он или другие отвечают на мой вопрос "*Почему так происходит? Как исправить?*"

Comment: @Monk, "*скопипастить*" - реализовать клонирование объекта?

Comment: @VladD, `event` потерял, да. Но и без него пример, выполняется с указанной проблемой

Comment: @VladD, C# 3.0 .Net 3.5

Comment: Нет, просто в локальную переменную перебить. Типа сделать `var currentDriver = driver`, а потом эту переменную попробовать в делегате использовать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это - особенность старой версии языка. Переменная цикла захватывается по ссылке, а не по значению - и потому к моменту возникновения события указывает на последнего водителя.

Решений тут три:

1. Если возможно, перейдите на современную версию языка. Это проще, чем вы думаете: Visual Studio Community Edition бесплатна для любого личного использования, обучения или работы над открытыми проектами.
2. Скопируйте значение переменной цикла в локальную переменную:

   ```
   foreach (var driver in ...) {
     var driver2 = driver;
     //...
   }
   ```
3. Смените тип коллекции `drivers` с массива на список (`List<Driver>`) - тогда вы получите метод `ForEach`, принимающий делегат:

   ```
   drivers.ForEach(driver => {
     //...
   });
   ```

Comment: Возможно, имеет смысл добавить текст о том, что же поменялось в свежих версиях языка.

Comment: @VladD мне кажется, это очевидно

Comment: Мне кажется, это очевидно нам с вами, но не новичкам.

Comment: Можно указать на неточность? Переменная цикла таки захватывается по ссылке, просто это каждый раз новая переменная. Проверить можно, захватив её в двух лямбдах и изменив значение в одной из лямбд.

Comment: Ага, вот всё же observable difference: http://ideone.com/FlVAEg

Answer (score 5):

Небольшое уточнение/дополнение к правильному ответу @Pavel Mayorov.

В C# до 5-ой версии цикл

```
foreach (var driver in drivers)
{
    // тело цикла
}
```

раскрывался примерно в такую конструкцию:

```
using (var en = drivers.GetEnumerator())
{
    Driver driver; // вне цикла
    while (en.MoveNext())
    {
        driver = en.Current;
        // тело цикла
    }
}
```

Поэтому все замыкания видели одну и ту же переменную `driver`, которая менялась с каждой итерацией цикла. И значит, при приходе события `Started` у этой переменной было уже «финальное» значение.

Начиная с версии 5.0, цикла стал раскрываться в другую конструкцию:

```
using (var en = drivers.GetEnumerator())
{
    while (en.MoveNext())
    {
        Driver driver = en.Current; // внутри цикла
        // тело цикла
    }
}
```

И значит, каждое замыкание теперь видит *свою* переменную `driver`, только для этой итерации. Таким образом, в C# 5+ ваш код будет вести себя ожидаемым образом.

---

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [*Closing over the loop variable considered harmful*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score 0):

Ваш delegate захватывает переменную driver (это именно closure), а когда машины стартуют, то в ней находится последний в списке водитель, он же Вася. Как уже посоветовали, попробуйте "внутри форича скопипастить водителя в переменную" (лучше прямо driver.Name) и посмотрите на результат. Правильнее всего, конечно, в Car иметь ссылку на Driver

Comment: Не совсем ясно, как применяется термин "*скопипастить*" к ссылочному объекту. Речь о клонировании?

Comment: @4per нет, речь шла о копировании. Расписал подробнее в своем ответе.