# Передача примитивного типа в делегат

Tags: c#

Не первый раз встречаю подобный пример кода в сети:

```
 delegate void Function() ;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     List<Function> functions = new List<Function>() ;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
           functions.Add(delegate{
                  Console.WriteLine(i);
            }) ;
     }

     functions[0]();

   }
```

В список методов добавляется новый метод, выводящий в консоль значение локальной переменной i. Её область видимости - цикл for. За ним по всем правилам языка, которые я знаю, она перестаёт существовать. По идее, в создаваемую функцию должно передаться её значение. Но судя по поведению, i остаётся ссылкой на изначальное определение в цикле. В итоге результат выполнения кода равен 10. Кто может объяснить подобное поведение либо хотя дать ссылку на мануалы, где это разъясняется?

Comment: Это объясняется в любом учебнике. Называется замыкание

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо. Оно самое. К слову, не во всех учебниках. Даже не предполагал, что в c#  есть это понятие

Comment: [However, the lifetime of a captured outer variable is extended at least until the delegate or expression tree created from the anonymous function becomes eligible for garbage collection.](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#captured-outer-variables)

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Установка анонимного метода обработчиком события в цикле foreach](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/583627/186999)